# Why am I getting an Errno 111 Connection Refused error when running a script from Rana Khalil tutorial on Port Swigger labs?

Tags: python, sql, proxy

I have been trying to fix this for so long and i cant find the way out! Probably is something really basic but i'm also a super newbie!
I'm trying to use the script from Rana's lab 12 tutorial on VS Code, i got my foxyproxy extension off as Rana also have it off in her video. When i run the script i get this message:

```
(+) Retrieving admin password...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 96, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 86, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
```

Every exception is related to the same error (Errno 111)
At the end i also get this message, maybe is useful for debugging:

```
raise ProxyError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ProxyError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='0a2300d1044bbd44841e8c9f00440003.web-security-academy.net', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: / (Caused by ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f5322f2e910>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111] Connection refused')))
```

Does anyone knows what is the problem??

Thank you very much in advance and have a nice day all!

I tried to run a script from Rana Khalil tutorial on Port Swigger labs it should work and retrieve the admin password but i'm getting a errno 111 as the seem to be a problem with the proxies